# Como percorrer listas?

Tags: java, lista

Queria uma solução para percorrer uma List prática.

Não precisa mostrar nenhum resultado, pois vou precisar percorrer uma lista de pessoas (objetos) e gerar um contas a receber de cada um, mas primeiro preciso saber como posso percorrer esta lista.

Comment: Por que limitar-se a `ArrayList` ? A resposta será válida para qualquer `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supondo que `listaPessoas` é uma lista do objeto `Pessoa`.

Assim:

```
for(Pessoa pessoa : listaPessoas)
{
     pessoa.fazerAlgumaCoisa();
}
```

Ou então

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaPessoas.size(); i++)
{
    listaPessoas.get(i).fazerAlgumaCoisa();
}
```

Comment: Uma desatenção: `listaPessoas[i]` é para arrays. Seria `listaPessoas.get(i).fazerAlgumaCoisa();`

Comment: Obrigado @Piovezan. Falha minha, é o costume com C#.

Answer (score 1):

Só complementando a resposta do renan, não é necessário usar o lista.stream() para utilizar o método forEach, se a lista qual você deseja iterar implementar a interface Collection você pode usar o forEach direto, exemplo:

```
lista.forEach(elemento -> /* faz algo */);
```

Comment: Bem lembrado, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Além das respostas do jbueno, você também pode usar um [iterator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ArrayListiterator.htm) para percorrer um ArrayList.

Convém ressaltar que o foreach é uma forma de açúcar sintático do iterator. Portanto, ambos tem o mesmo resultado. Apenas a título de curiosidade.